# Local path doesn't exist...and apk file is not generating

Tags: android

When i run application on my connected device, after selecting an device it shows unexpected error,local path doesn't exist.

Comment: clean and rebuilt it!!!

Comment: i did , doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle check if gradle is updated to latest.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
```

After that clean and rebuild your project.